# Can I use the same credit card to enter a lounge twice?

Tags: legal, india, airports, lounges

I'm not exactly sure if this is the correct Stackexchange to ask this, but here's hoping.

I have a 5 hour layover in Kolkata Airport(India) and my credit card allows me to use the lounge(I have 4 free access in a quarter) but it's limited to 3 hour per visit. So, once my 3 hours expire, is it possible to enter using the same card again?

Comment: Which lounge is this? Which credit card? What do the terms and conditions of both say?